# Reshape dataframe from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

my df:

```
d = {'project_id': [19,20,19,20,19,20], 
     'task_id': [11,22,11,22,11,22], 
     "task": ["task_1","task_1","task_1","task_1","task_1","task_1"], 
     "username": ["tom","jery","tom","jery","tom","jery"],
     "image_id":[101,202,303,404,505,606],
     "frame":[0,0,9,8,11,11],
     "label":['foo','foo','bar','xyz','bar','bar']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So my df, is long format, in some duplicate and only `image_id` is unique.
I trying pivot my df, with `pd.pivot` and `pd.merge` reshape to wide format by `username`.
My code:

```
pd.pivot(df, index=['task','frame','image_id'], columns = 'username', values='label')
```

My output:
[image: actual]

I expected(or want to reach):
[image: expected]

So, as you see, I don't really need `image_id` in my output. Just summary, which user use tag per frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) after the `pivot`:

```
(pd.pivot(df, index=['task','frame','image_id'],
          columns='username', values='label')
   .groupby(level=['task','frame']).first()
)
```

Or use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='first'`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['task','frame'],
               columns='username', values='label',
               aggfunc='first')
```

Output:

```
username      jery   tom
task   frame            
task_1 0       foo   foo
       8       xyz  None
       9      None   bar
       11      bar   bar
```

Comment: Its strange in example work perfect, but in real data, column 'frame' with values not sorted and order, changed like reset. Where in data values like [0,0,7,7,8,8,9], after pivot its reset to [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] . Difference from example to real data, column task have more than one value (i.g. task1, task2)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, `pivot` sorts the data. You can reorder after with `sort_index` on the desired level. You can also `pivot` on `index=['frame','task']` then `swaplevel`

Comment: Lets me understand, it's ok that will be sorted and ordered. If data not corrupted, (ig, no changes in data, no adding or removing). Its fine.